# Setting specified flags before serializing objects

Tags: c#, reflection, xml-serialization

We have a schema that we serialize and deserialize into an object hierarchy.
Some elements are optional in the schema. The xsd tool creates a cs file that inserts a property for each optional element. This property ends in "Specified", i.e. nameSpecified tells the serializer and deserializer to include the optional "name" element when processing.
I'm trying to write a method that rips through the object hierarchy using reflection and if a property has a value and it has a "Specified" corresponding property, I want to set the Specified property to true.

I've tried to do this using reflection, ie.

```
 foreach(PropertyInfo p in MyObject
             .GetType()
             .GetNestedTypes()
             .GetType()
             .GetProperties()
            {
               if the field name ends in Specified check if
               there is a field with the same name without Specied. 
               If there is, and that field name has a value, then set 
               the field name that ends in Specified to true;
            }
```

Its the middle bit that I'm having trouble with. I preferably don't want to rip through the hierarchy and create a list of properties ending in Specified and then rip through it again to see if the corresponding name without the ending "Specified" exists and then check if it has a value. And the rip through it again to update all the Specified fields to true. Seems a bit of a long way around :(

Anyone have any bright ideas?